# RabbitMQ RPC between Java and .NET

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to implement a RabbitMQ RPC between Java (acting as a client) and a .NET application (server/worker) using the RabbitMQ .NET library?

It seems like it should be possible, as RabbitMQ broker handles the queues and the socket connections are established between party and the RabbitMQ broker.

Are there any practical considerations in doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  In fact, my company uses RabbitMQ for that very reason - it offers a platform-neutral (as close as possible anyway) way to communicate between different applications.  So in theory, I could have Java applications running on Linux and .NET applications running on Windows, and everything works together just fine.

You will need to come up with a common serialization format for your messages; I recommend using JSON as there are JSON libraries in every major programming language.

If you have any trouble with the RabbitMQ .NET library, feel free to post more questions :-)